# How can I convert a numeric date into a character date with the month name in a different field in a form? (Access)

Tags: vba, ms-access

What I'm trying to accomplish is having a numeric date in a field/form generate a date which uses the month name in a different field in the same form.

For example, if 1/31/2021 is selected in the date field on the form, I need another field in the table to be populated (and visible on the form as a text box) with January 31, 2021. I'm currently trying to trigger it by when the date selction field changes as an event. I'm fumbling around with Format, DatePart, MonthName etc, but just can't get the right combination to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Set the *ControlSource* of the other textbox to:

```
=[YourFirstTextbox]
```

Set the property *Format* of the other textbox to: *mmmm dd, yyyy*